# Flask app has no permission to write into a data on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, permissions

I am running Flask on an Ubuntu server using Nginx and Gunicorn btw. and when i try to use the

```
with open(encrypted_file_name, 'wb') as out:
                pdf_writer.write(out)
```

command, the application returns an error and the logs show that the command `open` has no permissions to execute.
From the logs:

```
File "/home/admin/flask/application.py", line 251, in site_pdfencryption
    pdf_file.save(file_path)
  File "/home/admin/flask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3066, in save
    dst = open(dst, "wb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/admin/flask/static/pdf/Python_Flask_Code_Prettier.pdf'
```

//EDIT:
The codeline where the issue happens is this one.

```
    file_path = '/home/admin/flask/static/pdf/' + secure_filename(pdf_file.filename) # UBUNTU_PATH
    # file_path = 'static\pdf\\' + secure_filename(pdf_file.filename) # WINDOWS_PATH

    pdf_file.save(file_path)
```

Comment: Does that filename exist already?

Comment: yes the file name gets queried when a file gets uploaded as you see here from the code

`if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files:
            pdf_file = request.files['file']`

Comment: i tried the code on my local machine on windows and it works absolutly fine! i think there is a permission issue depending on ubuntu but i have no idea which permissions

Comment: Have you tried running `chmod 755 /path/to/script` and see if that sorts it?

Comment: yes didnt helped